# Reference for shtuka and trace formula

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, rt.representation-theory, automorphic-forms, langlands-conjectures

I really want to learn the work of Laurent Lafforgue and the joint work of Zhiwei Yun and Wei Zhang. They both involve shtuka and trace formula, which I only know the basic idea. So I would like to know is there a road map to learn these works?

Especially, I notice Professor Laumon's book Cohomology of Drinfeld Modular Variety deals with drinfeld module and automorphic representation over function field. Is this book a good start point?

I would appreciate any suggestion for references for Shtuka, trace formula or any relevant topic. A road map will be fantastic!

Comment: For function field arithmetic in general there's Goss book "Basic Structures of Function Field Arithmetic". He discuss shtukas from scratch.